# 8 Drawer Desk Conditional Probability Problem: Understanding Event A in the numerator.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Problem:

A desk has eight drawers.  There is a probability of 1/2 that someone placed a letter in one of the desk's eight drawers and a probability of 1/2 that this person didn't place a letter in any of the desk's eight drawers.  You open the first 7 drawers and find that they are all empty.  What is the probability that the 8th drawer has a letter in it?

---

Let "A" be the probability the letter is in the 8th drawer, and let B be the event that the first 7 are empty.

After getting this problem wrong and checking the answer, the solution states that the numerator is given by $P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B) = (1/2)(1/8)$.  What I don't understand is why $P(A) = 1/2$.  $P(A)$ is the probability that the letter is in the 8th drawer, which should be itself conditioned on whether the letter is in the desk, making it $P(A) = (1/2)(1/8) = 1/16$.  Yet multiple solutions to this problem maintain that the joint probability is $(1/2)(1/8)$, where $A = 1/2$ and $B = 1/8$, instead of $P(A \cap B) = (1/16)(1/8)$.

Why is this so?  What logic am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us call event $A$ something else than you have it.  Let event $A$ be the event that there was a letter placed at all somewhere within the eight desks (*as opposed to what you write with $A$ being the event that the eighth desk has a letter in it*).  This should be easier to conceptualize.

$\Pr(A\cap B)$ here being the probability that there was a letter placed in one of the desks (*event $A$*) and the first seven desks being empty (*event $B$*).

It is **wrong** to call this $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  This manipulation is *only* allowed when $A$ and $B$ are *independent events*.  Here it is clear that they are not independent since if $A$ were false... i.e. if there was no letter placed anywhere... then *of course* the first seven desks would be empty.  That is to say, $\Pr(B\mid A^c)=1$ which is not equal to $\Pr(B)<1$ since there exists nonzero probability that one of the first seven desks actually has something in it.

Thankfully, we can still manipulate things here using the "*multiplication principle of probability*", a rephrasing of the definition of conditional probability.  We have that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$.  Here, $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{1}{2}$ as stated in the problem statement with the phrase "*There is a probability of 1/2 that someone placed a letter in one of the desk's eight drawers.*"  Then, we can assume from the wording of the problem that had there been a letter placed in one of the drawers that each of the drawers should have equally likely been the one to have the letter placed in it.  That makes $\Pr(B\mid A) = \dfrac{1}{8}$ since for the first seven to be empty given that there was a letter placed, this occurs exactly when the letter was placed in the eighth drawer.

---

To answer the question the problem was asking us to, "*What is the probability that the eighth desk has a letter in it given the first seven did not?*" that is asking us to find $\Pr(A\mid B)$.  We use definition of conditional probability and/or Bayes' Theorem.

$$\Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}=\dfrac{\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)}$$

$$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to take a frequentist viewpoint of the problem, which may help with developing one's intuition.

Suppose there are $16$ such identical desks, in which the drawers are each numbered from $1$ to $8$.  For the first group of $8$ desks, the $k^{\rm th}$ desk has a letter placed in the $k^{\rm th}$ numbered drawer (so the first desk has a letter in drawer $1$, the second in drawer $2$, etc).  In the second group of $8$ desks, no letters are placed in any drawers.

Now, for the first desk, we pick $7$ distinct drawers at random to open.  Then for the remaining $15$ desks, we open the same numbered drawers.

For how many of these desks did we open the drawers and fail to find a letter?  Well, there are the $8$ desks that contained no letter.  But there is also exactly one desk in which the $7$ drawers that were opened happened to be the empty ones.  The other $7$ desks had a drawer with a letter, and those drawers were opened.  So there are $9$ desks that we saw with $7$ empty drawers.

And among those $9$ desks, exactly $1$ will have a letter in the remaining unopened drawer.

Answer (score 0):

If we were sure that one of the drawers had a letter, the probability that the 8th drawer had it would clearly be $\dfrac 1{16}$,

But half of the sample space has been "eaten away"

Thus $Pr={\dfrac1{16}\over\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac12}$